# WPF binding ObservableCollection to ListBox

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls

I'm trying to bind ObservableCollection to ListBox.
Output from debug doesn't show any binding errors, yet for some reason it doesn't work.

xaml:

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:nwsfeed"
x:Class="nwsfeed.MainWindow"
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
x:Name="Window">

    <ListBox x:Name="listBoxChannels" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Window, Path=App.ActiveProfile.Feeds}"
    DisplayMemberPath="Title"/>

</Window>
```

code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    public NwsfeedApp App { get; set; }
    // ..
}

public sealed class NwsfeedApp {
    public UserProfile ActiveProfile { get; set; }
    //..
}

public class UserProfile {
    private ObservableCollection<RSSFeed> feeds;
    public ObservableCollection<RSSFeed> Feeds { get { return feeds; } }
    //..
}
```

**edit**:
The problem is that when I have ObservableCollection as a public property of a MainWindow and I bind it like this, it works:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Window, Path=Items, Mode=OneWay}"
```

But when I do this, it doesn't:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Window, Path=App.ActiveProfile.Feeds, Mode=OneWay}"
```

**edit2**
I've implemented INotifyPropertyChanged in App, ActiveProfile and Feeds properties. ListBox still doesn't reflect the changes on collection, unless i call .Items.Refresh() on it.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is a bit vague, what do you see and what did you expect instead?

Comment: You should specify that the binding is oneway, seeing as the property doesn't have a set. Not sure if that will help, but I consider it a good practice.

Comment: No ListBox items are displayed even though there are items in collection which it is bind to.

Answer (score 1):

Implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx) on your classes.

Comment: While this is regularly the right answer for binding issues, it does not solve this problem. ObservableCollection doesn't need an additional  INPC implementation.

Comment: Do you need INotifyPropertyChanged? I would have thought the binding would still work, just not update if the property changes.

Comment: @ExitMusic precisely, which is why i said this doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @ExitMusic I dont see data in his properties yet. I assume the binding is working, but shows no data, because they are set later and no notification is raised.

Comment: That makes sense. What he could do is create the object in his constructor, and check if it displays. That way he knows the binding is sound

Comment: Doesn't ObservableCollection raise CollectionChanged and PropertyChanged events itself? I have data in my collection.

Comment: ObservableCollection raises CollectionChanged events but no PropertyChanged events if you assign the collection to feeds or if childs of the collection change. The INPC interface is implemented but you have to raise the notification.

Comment: The problem is that when I have ObservableCollection<RSSFeed> as a public property of a MainWindow and I bind it like this, it works:

ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Window, Path=Items, Mode=OneWay}"

But when I do this, it doesn't:
Binding ElementName=Window, Path=App.ActiveProfile.Feeds

Comment: Thats because when the observable collection is inside another property, then that property needs to call property changed. And if that property is inside another property, that parent property needs to implement it aswell.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks! Although I'm not quite sure how to do that.

Comment: I'm really confused. I'm new to WPF and all I'm trying to do is to bind a collection to ListBox and reflect the changes on collection.

Answer (score 0):

With lack of information, here's a shot in the dark:

You're trying to access `App` which is a static application property that isn't an instantiated variable within the code-behind of your window. The rest of the property path in your binding isn't evaluated because App cannot be found.

You probably want this:

```
ItemsSource="{x:Static local:App.ActiveProfile.Feeds}"
```

For the missing output, try `Tools->Options->Debugging->Output window->WPF Trace Settings` there you have options to see more or less information on the available WPF traces.

HTH,

Bab.

Comment: App isn't static. It's a property in MainWindow of Type NwsfeedApp.